# How to refresh the definition of a T-SQL user-defined function after a dependent object is redefined?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

Consider the following sequence of events:

1. A view v_Foo is defined
2. A user-defined function GetFoo() is defined that includes all columns from v_Foo (using 'Select * ...')
3. The definition of v_Foo changes and now includes more columns
4. I now want GetFoo() to include the new columns in v_Foo, but it still references the old definition

I can just re-run the script that created GetFoo in the first place and all will be well; but that's problematic for reasons I won't go into. Is there any other way to refresh the definition of a user-defined function so that it's in sync with its dependent objects?

Comment: Note: I know a lot of people will be distracted by the "Select * ..." and will be inclined to hassle me about that - please save your breath. I have my reasons.

Comment: With * you'll be missing aso all the SCHEMABINDING goodies: http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/12/596424.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short, easy answer is **No**.

You have to redefine the `RETURN TABLE` statement in Tabular UDF, `GetFoo()` 
whenever the definition of `v_Foo` changes.

But there is a way to get around it (translated as not practical).

1. Create a `DDL` trigger on [`ALTER_VIEW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189871(SQL.90).aspx) event.
2. Then use a dynamic SQL to create the `GetFoo()`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to see the definition of the function.  All you've said is it is using SELECT *.  Can you be more specific?

You also forgot to tell us what version of SQL Server you are using.  If >= 2005, have you looked at [`sp_refreshsqlmodule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshsqlmodule-transact-sql)?

Curious what your reasons are for insisting on SELECT *.  Lots of discussion about it here, but the cons still outweigh the pros by a large margin, IMHO:

- [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)